# Pyside: Drag & Drop into empty List?

Tags: qt, user-interface, drag-and-drop, pyside

I have two QTableViews, one filled with some entries, one empty. I want to select one Entry and drag/drop it into the empty list. But I just get the Drop working over an item. Is that even possible in PySide/QT? It's written in Python but I can handle C++ answers for Qt as well. Thanks in advance!

This is my DropClass Code:

```
class dropListView(QtGui.QTableView):
    dropped = QtCore.Signal(int)
    released = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(dropListView,self).__init__()
        #self.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet().style())

    def dropEvent(self,event):
        index = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        self.dropped.emit(index)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found it out myself:

adding this lines to the DropClass solved the issue:

```
    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.acceptProposedAction()
```